# Truth Value error in plotting SVM predicted values

Tags: python, matplotlib, svm

I am using SVM to train an imageset for a machine learning project at post graduate level.

The error displayed when the plot function is called:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

The traceback reads as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-5-10061f33ba63>", line 16, in <module>
plt.show(ix_train)

File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 253, in show
return _show(*args, **kw)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/pylab/backend_inline.py", line 41, in show
if close and Gcf.get_all_fig_managers():
```

Is there any plotting statement that I am missing, or a variable mismatch that I am doing?

I have followed the sklearn docs while trying to implement this function into my code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You supply an argument to `show`, `plt.show(something)`. That is not how `show` is meant to be used.
Instead you want to plot something and then show the previously created plot,

```
plt.plot(something)
plt.show()
```